# What is difference between getting adb logcats from appium by `getAll()` and `filter(Level.ALL)`

Tags: selenium, appium, logcat

Can anyone differentiate between

1. `List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();`
   and
2. `List<LogEntry> logEntries2 = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);`

Actually my need to is to clear `logEntries` after performed any click action on my app. Then i ran `adb logcat -c` command to clear those and again called `List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();` ideally it should give fresh logs as per i have cleared logs by `adb logcat -c`, but it doesn't. Then i performed `List<LogEntry> logEntries2 = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);` which is giving the fresh data after successful execution of `adb logcat -c`. So can anyone differentiate.